# Accessing ArrayList of interface objects

Tags: java, interface, arraylist

so I have this ArrayList that stores different kinds of objects like a coffe, soda, tea in an ArrayList called drinkList using an interface called drink.  I want to declare a drink object that has the components of the ith element in the drinkList, not knowing what type of object that is.  How would I do this?

```
public boolean contains (String drinkName, ArrayList drinkList){
 boolean ifThere = false; 
 int sizeList = drinkList.size() -1; 
 for(int i=0; sizeList > i; i++){ 
 Drink booleanDrink = drinkList.get(i);
  String booleanName = booleanDrink.getName(); 
     if (booleanName.equals(drinkName)){ 
        ifThere = true; 
} 
} 
return ifThere; 
}
```

Comment: This is what I have:
Drink aDrink = drinkList.get(5); 
(Comes up with incompatible types)

Comment: `ArrayList` uses a 0-based index, so to get the fifth element you'd use `drinkList.get(4);`

Comment: I think you're going to need to show your code to get an answer to this as the concept sounds ok.

Comment: public boolean contains (String drinkName, ArrayList drinkList){


    boolean ifThere = false;

    int sizeList = drinkList.size() -1;
    for(int i=0; sizeList > i; i++){
      Drink booleanDrink = drinkList.get(i);
      String booleanName = booleanDrink.getName();
      if (booleanName.equals(drinkName)){
        ifThere = true;
      }
    }
    return ifThere;
  }'

Comment: Edit your question to include your code instead of putting it in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the result of the `get` call to a `Drink` as:

```
Drink booleanDrink = (Drink) drinkList.get(i);
```

Or use an `ArrayList<Drink>` instead of a plain `ArrayList`.